# Why is my Windows service failing to log in to this database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows, windows-services, windows-security

This whole web of SQL Server and Windows permissions is so confusing to me.

I created a login at

```
Server > Security > Logins
```

with

```
Login name: foo
Password: xyz
Default database: MyDb
```

Then at

```
Server > Databases > MyDb > Security > Users
```

I created a user with

```
User name: bar
Login name: foo
Default schema: dbo
```

because that's what I want to log in with and execute `dbo` stuff with my Windows Service.

My Windows Service is running under

```
Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem
```

and my `App.Config` has

```
<add name="LocalDb" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-300NQR3\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDb;Integrated Security=False;User Id=bar;Password=xyz" />
```

The `OnStart` of my service tries to connect to the db through that connection and I get the exception

> Service cannot be started. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
>   (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'foo'.    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObj...

Comment: Does a tool like SQL Server Management Studio log in successfully with these new credentials?

Comment: You created the database account wrong. You need to grant access from the first login (the server level login) and pick which database and grant something like datareader.

Comment: Is Mixed Authentication mode enabled?

Comment: You are connecting to your db using user (bar); have you tried to connect using login (foo) instead (setting `User Id=foo;Password=xyz` in your connection string)?